# No matching rule when downloading

Tags: download, website, bittorrent, rules

When I try to download project maelstrom from BitTorrent, it comes up with an error: `no matching rule`. I have tried to restart my browser and also restart my computer. What more can I do? I am using Chrome update 53.

https://download-new.utorrent.com/endpoint/ut-browser/os/windows/track/beta

I was taken to this link from BitTorrent:
http://project-maelstrom.bittorrent.com/